# Is there an English translation of "The Legend of Oghuz Khagan"?

Tags: translation

This [tweet](https://twitter.com/incunabula/status/1153249918129192960) kicked off my interest in this topic.

AFAIK, "The Legend of Oghuz Khagan" is one of the classics in [Uyghur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uyghurs) literature and it has been called one of the great poetic epics of Uyghur history.

I've seen [a translation](http://blog.renren.com/share/235307721/4665878884) into Chinese by [Geng Shimin](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%80%BF%E4%B8%96%E6%B0%91).

Does an English translation exist of "The Legend of Oghuz Khagan"? The work doesn't seem to be very long, but I can't seem to find much info on it.

Comment: Have you tried searching for Oghuznameh/-nama? (the Uyghur cover title). 乌古斯可汗传说/The Legend of Oghuz Khagan is probably a "custom" Chinese translation and is probably not used by Western authors.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster I was able to find something based off of your comment. I posted an answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Harun Doğruyol](https://www.academia.edu/37520797/EPIC_AS_A_LITERARY_GENRE_AND_THE_TURKISH_EPIC_OGUZ_KHAN_) has written on the topic and has found similar issues:

> During my research I did not come across any English version of this epic,

but thankfully he also says:

> so I have translated the first and pagan version and have attached it to my article.

---

The Legendary Turkish Warrior (Alp) Oguz Khan and His Epic

The Birth of Oguz Khan

1. ……They said let it be.
   Here is his image:
2. After that they also got in happy and joyful mood
   One day
3. Their eyes brightened up, became colorful, filled in light
   That day Moon Khan gave birth to a boy
4. Bluish, sky-blue was his face
   Redd*ish was his mouth, like a fire was his color of face
5. Crimson were his eyes, dark was his face
   His eyebrows were more beautiful than fairies’, how black!
6. He came to his mother’s breast he took it and sucked milk
   He did not want to suck milk anymore
7. He wanted raw meat, meal and, food
   He wanted wine from his surroundings and, wanted to have fun
8. Immediately, he started to talk, utter and say
   After forty days he started to walk and play
9. His feet were as if they were ox’s feet
   His ankles were as if they were wolf’s ankles
10. His shoulders were similar to that of sable’s
    His chest is identical to that of a big bear’s
11. He was a human but full of hairs
    His body was covered with hairs
12. He herded the flocks of the horses he caught and rode them
    Days passed, so many years passed
13. Oguz also grew up and became a handsome hero
    The youth of Oguz Khan
    In that age! In that place!
14. There was a big forest inside Oguz’s homeland
    Lots of rivers and streams flowed through this forest
15. Lots of game animals live in the forest
    Lots of game birds also flew over it
16. In the forest did a big rhinoceros live
    It ate and didn’t let either animal or human live
17. It attacked herds and always ate horses
    It troubled people, took their lives
18. It never granted humans their lives
    Such a monster was it, it was that much frightful
19. There was a person who was very “Alp” (heroic, sublime, frightful, sacred Turkish warrior) called Oguz Khan
    In order to kill that rhinoceros he went to that spot
20. He took a spear and a sword with a shield and arrows
    He challenged the rhinoceros that it would die soon
21. He hunted a deer while hunting in the forest
    He tied it to a tree with a willow branch
22. He returned to his house before the morning broke
    When it was dawn he checked the deer
23. He realized that the rhinoceros had already swallowed the deer
    He caught a bear also instead of a deer
24. Taking off his golden belt of kingship
    He hanged the bear downstairs
25. It was morning again, it began to dawn
    He came and realized that the rhinoceros had taken his bear
26. Finally this case annoyed him extremely
    He approached the tree himself and stayed under it
27. When the rhinoceros came, it saw Oguz and stopped
    It hit Oguz’s shield with its head
28. Oguz hit its head with his spear
    Killing the rhinoceros Oguz saved his homeland
29. Beheading it with his sword he took its head
    e returned his home and delivered the news to his country
30. One day he saw a white falcon
    It perched on the rhinoceros and eating its intestine
31. He shot an arrow with his bow, the arrow killed the falcon
    He beheaded it then, he murmured himself:
32. “The rhinoceros ate both the deer and the bear”
    “My spear killed it, because it was made of iron”
33. “A little white falcon ate the huge rhinoceros”
    “The arrow and the bow killed it because it was made of copper”
34. One day
    Oguz’s marriage with the daughter of the sky
    While Oguz was begging of the God
35. The darkness fell suddenly, a light descended from the sky
    Such a light was it, brighter than the moon and the sun
36. Oguz Khan walked and approached the light
    He saw a girl sitting in the middle of the light
37. There was a beauty spot was on her head, as bright as a fire
    She was so beautiful, as if she was the North Star
38. Such a beautiful girl was she, the sky smiles with her when she similes
    When she wants to cry, the sky cries with her
39. The time Oguz saw the girl, he was overwhelmed
    He fell in love with her; he loved her whole heartily 
    He entered the bride’s chamber, got what he wanted
40. She became pregnant, after days and nights passed
    Her eyes brightened up when her three sons were born
41. They named the first son “Sun“ 
    They found the name “Moon” for the second son
    They were glad that third one’s name was “Star”
    Oguz’s marriage with the daughter of the ground
42. Oguz Khan went to the forest to hunt one day
    There was a tree standing in the middle of the lake
43. A girl was sitting in the cavity of the tree
    Her eyes were bluer than the sky, she was a God’s daughter
    Her hair was wavy as if a river wave
    Her tooth was like a pearl shining in her mouth
44. Anybody living in the world would say that
    Ah! Ah! We are dying! My God! We are dying!
45. They would say and shout and shout
    Like sweet milk’s becoming kumiss (traditional drink)
46. When Oguz saw the girl, he was out of mind
    An ember of fire entered his heart whatsoever
47. He loved her whole heartily, he took her hand
    He entered the bride’s chamber, got what he wanted
48. They named the first son “Sky“
    They found the name “ Mountain” for the second son
49. They were glad that third one’s name was “Sea”
    When Oguz heard this, he had his lineage praised with songs in his homeland
50. He gave a big feast
    He provided wealth to his homeland

    Missing part

Oguz-Khan’s becoming the “Supreme Khan” of the Turks

51. He gave orders to his inner homeland
    The people agreed to meet, went to Oguz
52. Oguz had forty tables prepared
    He had different kinds of food cooked with lots of wine
53. People sat at the tables drank so much kumiss
    So much wine was drunk and so much sweet was eaten
54. After the feast he gave this order
    “O! My men! and my nation!”
55. “I’m now your Khan”
    “Never let either the shield or the arrow fall from your hand”
56. “A seal that would lead us should become our sign
    “The Alps should become like wolves howling”
57. “With iron spears our country should become a forest”
    “Our hunting ground should be filled with the wild horses”
58. “Our country should abound with rivers and seas”
    “The sun in the sky should become our nation’s flag”
59. “The sky should become our tent”
    “The world should become my country and my nation should be plenty”
60. He also delivered his order to all round his country
    He informed the ambassadors, everybody learned it
61. In one of his messages, he addressed his nation as this:
    “Since I’m the supreme Khan of the Uighurs” (first settled Turkish tribe)
62. “I’m supposed to be the Khan of the world”
    “Every part of the world is under my rule”
63. “My wish is that you would obey me”
    “My request is that you should be ready for my order”
64. “Whoever submits to me will be rewarded”
    “He will be my comrade, he could always ask for my help”
65. “Anyone who does not obey me and rebels against me”
    “I will prepare my army, he is my enemy”
66. “I declare that I will attack and run over and suppress him”
    “I will destroy him, run over and hang him”
67. It was also in that age:
68. There was another Khan called Golden Khan
    He sent his messenger to Oguz Khan
69. He presented the rare rubies and gold and silver
    He sent diamonds and showed respect
70. Presenting the best gift, he made friends with him
    He surrendered himself to Oguz and also made him happy
    Oguz Khan’s raids in the west along the Idil River
71. There was a great and majestic Khan called Urum Khan
    He was dwelling on the left side of Oguz, he was Oguz’s neighbor
72. He had lots of cities and innumerable armies
    He ignored Oguz’s orders
73. He never followed Oguz’s orders and resisted him
    He said that “I would never obey you”
74. Oguz sent him a command, he ignored
    Oguz decided to destroy him
75. Oguz set off and raised a flag
    He crossed the skirts of the Ice Mountain in forty days
76. He had the tents set up, he fell asleep
    When the morning was about to break, a light entered his tent
77. A male wolf appeared, breathing
    A wolf with a blue mane, such a wolf with a bluish furry
78. He addressed Oguz as if it was a human being
    He began to utter some words as if it was a language
79. He said “O! Oguz, I know what your wish is”
    “You wanted to start a war in Urum’s province”
80. “O! Oguz I will lead your army”
    “I will walk in front of your army”
81. Hearing this Oguz had his tent rolled up
    When he went to his army, he was surprised to see this:
82. A big male wolf
83. lf like an advance guard
    With its blue mane, and blue hair, like a scout making way
84. He was walking in front of them
    Finally he stopped one day, after many days
85. Oguz’s army stopped, behind him
    There was a river called Idil-Müren
86. The war started suddenly, by the river bank
    With spears and arrows on the skirts of the Black-Mountain
87. There were lots of fights among the soldiers
    The people’s minds were confused, they were worried
88. Such a hard fight was it that
    The color of the water of Idil-Müren became full of red blood
89. Oguz Khan became successful and Urum Khan escaped
    He took his kingdom and his nation
90. Oguz’s tent was full of loot
    Whether dead or alive everything became his slave
    Oguz Khan’s raid to Kıpçak
91. Urum Kağan had a brother called Uruz
    Chief Uruz’s son survived too
92. Chief Uruz sent his son to a city
    A city set up on the mountain, by a secret river
93. Chief Uruz told him “the city should be protected”
    “Until the fight is over, the city should be preserved”
94. He said “Bring your people back after the war”
    Hearing this, Oguz stopped eating and drinking anything
95. Oguz moved his army, and reached the city
    Uruz sent a messenger to Oguz
96. He sent a lot of gold, silver, and pearl as gifts
97. He declared: “O! Oguz Khan you are my Khan”
    “My father gave me this city and said: “You are my son”
98. “Spare this city for me, it should be protected”
    “The city should be preserved until the fight is over”
99. “After the war, return back with the city under your rule”
    Chief Uruz said more
100. “If my father is an enemy of Oguz Khan”
     “Do not blame me, if my ancestor is guilty”
101. “I’m always with you under your rule”
     “I obey your command, I’m devoted to you”
102. “My state is your state”
     “Our generation is your descendant”
103. “God ordered you to rule the earth”
     “I submit to you my head and my country”
104. “I’m going to sent you my gifts and taxes”
     “I will always be your friend”
105. Oguz became happy with this brave man’s words
     Smiling, he bestowed him an authority to rule
106. He said “you gave me lots of gold and gifts”
     “You preserved your city so well”
107. “For protecting your city so well”
     “I gave you the name Saklap” (the preserver)
108. Oguz became friend with him, he moved his army
     He came to Idil River and stayed by the banks
109. The river called Idil was a big river
     Looking at the river, Oguz asked his chiefs:
110. “How could we pass this river?”
     There was a chief, he bowed to Oguz
111. He was a very clever chief called Uruğ :army chief
     He gave Oguz Khan advice
112. Searching the surrounding, he saw lots of trees and branches
     He cut and shaped the branches, he made a raft
113. Lying on the raft, he passed the Idil River
     Oguz became very happy and gave this order:
114. “Stay here, and be a sanjak (province) chief”
     “I declare that you will be called Kıpçak (trunk) from now on”
115. Oguz returned to his army and they set off again
     When they began to march, the wolf appeared
     Emergence of Turkish tribes “Karluk”
116. Such a wolf, a male wolf
     With blue hair and blue mane
117. This wolf said to Oguz
     “O! Oguz move your army now”
     “Take your people and your army with their horses”
     “I will lead you to the right way”
118. Oguz saw the wolf walking in front 
     The advance guards of the army were following him
119. Seeing this scene, Oguz became happy
     He rode his multi-colored horse happily
120. Oguz Loved his multi-colored horse whole heartily
     But the horse ran away to the mountain and disappeared
121. It was a big mountain covered with ice
     Its summit is too white because of the severe cold
122. There was a very brave very Alp chief in the army
     He was neither afraid of God nor Satan
123. He was not bothered with fatigue and cold
     He went to the mountain and after nine days
124. He caught the stallion, and pleased Oguz
     He was covered with snow
125. He looked like a snowman
     Seeing him, Oguz smiled at him
126. Declared “Stay here and be a chief of the chiefs here”
     Your name will be Karluk (snowy) forever
127. He gave him lots of diamonds and gifts
     He went on his way bestowing him presents
     Emergence of the Turkish tribes “Kalaç”
128. While Oguz was moving forward, He was surprised too much
     He saw a big house, its windows were made up of silver
129. The walls were made up of gold, the roof made up of iron
     There was no key, the door was locked
130. There was a soldier called Tömürdü Kagul in the army
     He was very skilful, Oguz ordered him
131. “You will stay here and you will open the door”
     “After you have entered the house, join the army later”
132. Oguz told this soldier to stay and open (kal! aç!)
     Therefore he named him Kalaç
     Curcet raid and emergence of Turkish tribes “Kanglı”
         One day
133. The wolf with blue hair and with mane disappeared
     Oguz realized this and stopped
134. He decided to have his tent set up there
     This was a barren area without fields, good enough to beat the enemy
135. The province called Curcet which had vast pastures
     And lots of wealth, lots of cattle, lots of horses
136. Curcet Khan had lots of gold and silver
137. He had lots of diamonds
138. Curcet Kagan with his army and people 
     Rebelled against Oguz Khan
139. Oguz spilled the enemy’s blood with spear and sword
     Oguz suppressed and overcame him
140. Oguz killed him beheading
     He divided the loots among his men and made the nation submit to him
141. Oguz’s officials and soldiers and nation
     Took and gathered all the countless goods
142. The horses, and oxen and mules were not enough
     To carry the goods taken in the war
143. There was a soldier clever and, experienced in the army
     His name was Barmaklıg Cosun Billig a very capable man
144. He designed an oxcart, this skillful man of Oguz
     Put everything in taken during the war
145. In order to pull the oxcart, the living beings were harnessed in front
     The loots were put at the back of the oxcart
146. Oguz’s chiefs and nation were surprised
     They designed oxcarts similar to his
147. When the oxcarts were moving, they shouted: Kanga! Kanga! 
     Therefore their names became “Kanga” (oxcart)
148. Seeing this Oguz laughed at 
     And ordered “The living beings should pull the lifeless”
149. “Your name is now Kangalug, and the oxcart is your sign”
     He left them ad proceeded
     Oguz’ raids to the south
150. The holy wolf with blue hair and blue mane appeared
     India, Tangut too became Oguz land
151. Oguz marched towards Syria
     He fought, beheaded, added it to his country
152. This should be known by everybody
     There was a province called Barkan in the south
153. It was a wealthy area with lots of game bird
     The climate was hot; it was a region of the wild animals
154. It had lots of gold and silver
     The People there were dark skinned by divine
155. The Khan of the Region was called Masar (Egypt)
     Oguz went there, fought hard and dominated
156. When he had a victory, Masar Khan escaped
     He took over the land and added it to his country
157. He took countless properties and horses, his friends became happy
     He returned his homeland and his enemies became desperate
     Oguz granted the title of Khan to his six sons
158. This should be mentioned, everybody should know
     There was an old man under Oguz’s service
159. White bearded, gray haired, very experienced
     A very noble man, clever and considerate
160. His title is “Tüşimel” in other words: the vizier of The Khan
     His name is Sublime Turk, Oguz’s distinguished man
161. He had a dream during his sleep. 
     He saw a golden bow, and three silver arrows
162. The golden bow was extending from the east to the west
     Three silver arrows were flying to the north
163. He told Oguz about his dream
     He interpreted his dream, with inspiration
164. He said: “My dream should bring you peace and comfort”
     “I hope it will bring unity and security to my Khan”
165. “What I had in my dream, should come to truth
     With the help of the God of Sky
166. The earth should be filled with your tribe
     God should grant the earth to your linage
167. Oguz was pleased with the Sublime Turk’s words
     Oguz took his advice and comforted to it
168. When he woke up in the morning
     He had his younger and older sons called
169. He said: “I want to hunt”
     “As I’m old now I do not have the courage”
170. “Sun, Moon, Star go to the east”
     “Sky, Mountain and Sea go to the west”
171. Hearing this order, three of his son went to the east
     Three of them went to the west
172. Sun, Moon, Star hunted a lot of games and birds
     They found a golden bow
173. They presented it to the Khan, he became happy and smiled
     He divided the bow into three parts
174. He said: “O! my sons the bow is yours
     “Your arrows should reach the sky”
175. Sky, Mountain, Sea hunted lots of games and birds
     They found three silver arrows
176. They presented it to the Khan, he became happy and smiled
     He divided the arrows into three parts
177. He said: “O! my sons this arrow is yours
     “Your arrows should reach the sky”
     Oguz gave a big feast
178. After saying all these, Oguz organized a general meeting
     The chiefs and the people came and greeted each other
     Everybody came and be seated in Oguz tent

Missing part

179. In Oguz’s own big tent

Missing part

180. He had a forty fathom tall pole erected on the right side of his tent
     He put a golden chicken at the top of the pole
     He tied a white sheep at the bottom of the pole
181. He had a forty fathom tall pole erected on the right left of his tent
     He put a silver chicken at the top of the pole
     He tied a black sheep at the bottom of the pole
182. On his right side there were Grey Arrows, on the left Three Arrows
     They sat down and had fun more than forty days
183. They ate and drank and attained their desire
     Oguz divided his country among his sons and gave it to his sons
184. He said “O! my sons”
     “So many wars have I been through, so many borders have I crossed”
185. “So many spears and arrows have I thrown”
     “So long distances have I traveled on horse, so many enemies did I make cry”
186. “I have made happy most of my friends”
     “Thank God I have paid my debt”
     “To the God of Sky”
     “I give this country to you, this country is now yours”

Translated by Harun DOGRUYOL (Based on Togan Zeki Velidi, Oğuz Destanı, Enderun Kitapevi, 2. Basım, Istanbul, 1982